# Include native libraries in a JAR - IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar, java-native-interface, lwjgl

I recently got into LWJGL, and it's working fine in the IDE. But when I export my project to a JAR file, it's not working similarly to in the IDE.

I know how I can include my LWJGL JAR in the game JAR file, but I want the natives in there as well so people don't need to download lots of files to run my game.

How can I do this in IntelliJ?

When I run the JAR file, I get a `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path` error. I know I can do `-Djava.library-path="<path_to_native>"`, but I want my program to be easy-to-use for others. The easiest would be to just have one file - the JAR. So is it possible to get the natives inside the JAR? - how?

Comment: @httpdigest I have no idea what version I use... I just followed a tutorial. I downloaded it from [here.](http://www.mediafire.com/file/tjfu506bt9tsp56/Libs.zip)

Comment: @httpdigest I can't find out how to add the natives now? I added the lwjgl.jar file and I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`