# LWJGL can't find org/lwjgl/openal/OpenALException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lwjgl

I wanted to have music and sounds in my program since a long time now.
So I tried this thing called LWJGL, and it worked fine. But when I built a jar, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599426/include-native-libraries-in-a-jar-intellij) happened.

I got a suggestion saying that I need to use LWJGL 3, so I downloaded it and tried to set it up. But when I now run my program from IntelliJ, I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/openal/OpenALException

What can I do?

Comment: Have added the jar to the classpath after downloading?

Comment: Try Version 2.8.3 this included the excpetion class: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/l/Downloadlwjgl283jar.htm

Comment: ...but in my previous question a dude said I needed to use LWJGL 3 in order to do what I want to do

Comment: please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Do you not know what a stacktrace is?